# Is there a way to render the depth buffer covering all pixels?

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to render a transparent image with a depth buffer, but the issue I'm having is that the depth buffer doesn't cover all the pixels in the final image. The pixels are effectively getting antialiased outside the depth buffer. Is there any way to get the depth to write to all affected pixels?

Here's an example:

[image: colour] [image: depth]

Thanks!